# POJO to JSON in Play framework

Tags: java, json, playframework-2.0

Trying to get Play 2.0 to return JSON from a POJO. But I recieve the error

```
The method toJson(Writes<A>) in the type Json is not applicable for the arguments (Product)
```

And my code is:

```
public static Result index(String date) {
     Product item = new Product();
    return ok(Json.toJson(item));

   }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Make sure you import the right `Json` class using `import play.libs.Json`.

You probably used `play.api.libs.Json` which is targeted for the Scala API, not the Java API.