# Which playframework Json java class to use?

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.2

When one tries to include a reference to the Json class in order to create a new Json object in eclipse, he will be asked whether to import `play.api.libs.json.Json` or `play.libs.Json`.

Currently it is not clear in the playframework [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaJsonRequests) which one is the right one.

Comment: FYI, your link is to a very old version of the documentation.  Here's the current link: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJsonRequests

Comment: I had not noticed that. When googling, im often redirected to older versions of the documentation and I had the impression (from previous attempts of renaming the version directly in the uri) that there was not always an equivalent page withing the newest version. It could be nice if the old pages displayed a link to the same page with the newest play version and if you clicked on `Browse version X` you were redirected to the equivalent page in that play version instead of the Home documentation of that play version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **rule of the thumb** in Play 2.x - that for Scala you are using classes with `api` package inside i.e.:

```
play.api.libs.json.Json
play.api.cache.Cache
play.api.i18n.Lang
```

And for Java - use almost the same but **without** `api` package

```
play.libs.Json
play.cache.Cache
play.i18n.Lang
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `play.libs.Json` and it is actually mentioned in [POJO to JSON in Play framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15451726/pojo-to-json-in-play-framework) .

However, I thought that it could be beneficial to post it as a more specific Q&A on that regard so it is easier for someone with the same problem to find the answer.